# Aggregation function for sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, aggregate-functions

Execute below script for create test table.

```
create table if not exists t1 (id1 int,id2 int);
```

Now, table is created, and it is empty table.

Execute below script,

```
select max(id1), max(id2) from t1
```

It will return below result(one row).

```
max(id1)      max(id2)
-----------   --------
<null>        <null>
```

Execute below script,

```
select max(id1), max(id2) from t1 group by id1,id2
```

It will return below result(no result).

```
max(id1)      max(id2)
-----------   --------
```

Is there somebody explain the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#minggunc) says:

> The `max()` aggregate function returns the maximum value of all values in the group. [...] Aggregate `max()` returns `NULL` if and only if there are no non-`NULL` values in the group.

In your first query, there is one group which does not have any records.

In your second query, there is no group.